# How to update rowCount of QTableView with QSortFilterProxy?

Tags: qt, qtableview, rowcount, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a `QTableView` with a custom `QSortFilterProxy` to be able to search my data over multiple Columns. That works great so far.

Now I would like to display the row count. I would like to have something like **current displayed rows / total amount of rows in database**.

It's absolutely no problem to get `rowCount` on program start, but I am not exactly sure how I could recalculate the currently visible rows when the data has been filtered through my `QSortFilterProxy`.

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare return values of `rowCount()` function of your source and `QSortFilterProxyModel` models.
For example, suppose `model` is a pointer to your `QSortFilterProxyModel`, than:

```
int filteredRowCount = model->rowCount();
int allRowCount = model->sourceModel()->rowCount();
```

Comment: As you might have guessed, I am rather new to Qt. Could you elaborate on your answer? How should I tell my QSortFilterModel to return it's rowCount?

Comment: That was easier than I thought, thank you.
I have been searching for a means of updating the rowCount from within my filtered Model. Now I just read the count of current visible rows after I issued a new search.